# How to call javascript from different window?

Tags: javascript

I am working with IE9. Want to open a popup window from a page, and from the popup, how to call the javascript code in the page (not the popup window)?

There will not be a cross domain issue as I am going to load a page from the same domain of the page into the popup window.

Comment: `window.opener.yourMethod()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Cory said, use `window.opener` to get the parent window's `window`. Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dmnqk/

```
function openPopup() {
    var w = window.open("", "");
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.parentWindowFunction();<\/script>");
    w.document.close();
}

function parentWindowFunction() {
    alert("called");
}
```

Of course, my use of `document.open/write/close` is simply to create my own page that calls the parent window's function (technically, it should really have `<html><head></head><body>SCRIPT HERE</body></html>`. All your popup's page would need is the call to `window.opener.parentWindowFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.opener` to access functions in the global (`window`) namespace of the page that opened the popup:

#### Opener

```
function functionFromOpener() {
    return "wharrgarbl";
}
```

#### Popup

```
alert(window.opener.functionFromOpener());
```

Obligatory jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yLu2/1/

That said, I think it's a better idea to use in-page DHTML dialogs. (Or possibly it's that browser windows that aren't resizeable / don't have address bars bug me that much.)